# Why didn't Lily Potter become a ghost?

Tags: harry-potter

It seems that, given she has given her life for Harry, why not have become a ghost and helped Harry, or even 'mothered' him as much as a ghost could, too. If I were Harry, I think I would have preferred this to never knowing his mother. And I think that Lily herself should have preferred this to see her son grow up, even help protect him especially in a time of peril in the Wizarding World.